# Uninitialized variable issue in Perl program

Tags: perl, scope

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw(looks_like_number);

sub term_value();
sub factor_value();

sub expression_value()
{   
    $num = @_;
    @expression = $_[0];
    print "expression[0]: " . $expression[0] . "\n";

    $index = $_[$num-1];
    print "index: $index\n";

    $result = &term_value(@expression, $index);
    $more = 1;

    while($more)
    {
        $op = $expression[$index];
        print "$op\n";
        if ($op eq "+" || $op eq "-")
        {
            $index++;
            $value = &term_value(@expression, $index);
            if ($op eq '+')
            {
                $result = $result + $value;
            } else {
                $result = $result - $value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $more = 0;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

sub term_value()
{
    $num = @_;
    @expression = $_[0];
    print "expression[0]: " . $expression[0] . "\n";

    $index = $_[$num-1];
    print "index: $index\n";
    $result = &factor_value(@expression, $index);
    $more = 1;

    while($more)
    {
        $op = $expression[$index];
        if ($op eq "*" || $op eq "/")
        {
            $index++;
            $value = &factor_value(@expression, $index);
            if ($op eq '*')
            {
                $result = $result * $value;
            } else {
                $result = $result / $value;
            }
        } else {
            $more = 0;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

sub factor_value()
{
    $num = @_;
    @expression = $_[0];
    print "expression[0]: " . $expression[0] . "\n";

    $index = $_[$num-1];
    print "index: $index\n";
    $result = 0;
    $c = $expression[$index];
    if ($c eq '(')
    {
        $index++;
        $result = &expression_value(@expression, $index);
        $index++;
    } else {
        while (looks_like_number($c))
        {
            $result = 10 * $result + $c - '0';
            $index++;
            $c = $expression[$index];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

#Collect argument and separate by character
@one_char = split(//, $ARGV[0]);

$index = 0;
$result = &expression_value(@one_char, $index);

print $result . "\n";
```

My console returns these warnings:

```
Use of uninitialized value $op in string eq at eval.pl line 58.
Use of uninitialized value $op in string eq at eval.pl line 58.
Use of uninitialized value $op in string eq at eval.pl line 25.
Use of uninitialized value $op in string eq at eval.pl line 25.
```

about the $op variable being uninitialized. I'm thinking this may be a scope problem...but I can't figure it out. I've tried everything I could think of (initializing the variable outside of the loop, etc.), but none of it seems to make a difference when running the program. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: More than a hundred lines and no `strict`? Prototypes? What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: This was just a quick translation of C++ code used to evaluate an expression string (such as "1+2*3).

Comment: Remove the `()` after the name in each subroutine declaration, you keep saying that word but I do not think it means what you think in means.  Place `use strict;` at the top of the code, fix every error you get. Repost.  While doing the former, repeat `Perl is not C++` over and over again :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're only using package (~global) variables, which is a huge problem given that you are using recursive functions! Start by adding

```
use strict;
```

Primarily, this will identify the variables you haven't declared. Use `my` to declare them in the appropriate scope.

---

You're trying to pass arrays to the subs, but you're failing. The only thing that can be passed to a sub is a list of scalars. If you want to pass an array to a sub, you'll need to pass a reference (~pointer) to the array.

```
sub foo {
   my ($expressions, $index) = @_;
   print($expressions->[$index], "\n");
}

foo(\@expressions, $index);
```

This is the reason you're getting the warnings. You are assigning one element to an array (`@expression = $_[0]`), then you try to index the second or later element.

---

By using prototype `()`, you're telling Perl the sub takes no arguments. Then you use `&` to tell Perl to ignore the prototype so you can pass arguments to your subs. Get rid of both the `()` after the sub names and `&` before sub calls.

---

```
my $more = 1;
while ($more) {
   ...
   if (cond) {
      ...
   } else {
      $more = 0;
   }
}
```

can be reduced to

```
while (1) {
   ...
   last if !cond;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Higher Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/) has a [chapter on parsing](http://hop.perl.plover.com/book/pdf/08Parsing.pdf). See section 8.1.2 for how you would build an expression parser and evaluator from scratch.

You can also take a look at the [demo calculator script](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DCONWAY/Parse-RecDescent-1.965001/demo/demo_calc.pl) provided with [Parse::RecDescent](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parse-RecDescent).

Just out of curiosity, I wanted to see what can be achieved without using parsers. The following script makes a lot of assumptions, but "works" for the simple cases.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Regexp::Common qw(balanced number);

die "Need expression\n" unless @ARGV;
my ($expression) = @ARGV;

my $result = evaluate_expression($expression);

printf(
    "'%s' evaluated to %g\n",
    $expression, $result
);

my $expected = eval $expression;

unless ($result == $expected) {
    die "Wrong result, should have been '$expected'\n";
}

sub evaluate_expression {
    my ($expression) = @_;

    my $n = qr!$RE{num}{real}!;
    my $mul = qr![*/]!;
    my $add = qr![+-]!;
    my $subexpr = qr!$RE{balanced}{-parens=>'()'}{-keep}!;

    1 while
        $expression =~ s!
            $subexpr
        !
            my $s = $1;
            $s =~ s{(?:^\()|(?:\)\z)}{}g;
            evaluate_expression($s)
        !gex;

    1 while
        $expression =~ s!($n) \s* ($mul) \s* ($n)!"$1 $2 $3"!geex;

    1 while
        $expression =~ s!($n) \s* ($add) \s* ($n)!"$1 $2 $3"!geex;

    return $expression;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> z "((1+1)*3 +2)*5"
'((1+1)*3 +2)*5' evaluated to 40

C:\Temp> z "(1+1)*3 + 2*5"
'(1+1)*3 + 2*5' evaluated to 16
```

But, of course, it's fragile:

```
C:\Temp> z "2*3+2*5"
'2*3+2*5' evaluated to 610
Wrong result, should have been '16'
```

Answer (score 0):

As a bit of a corollary to Sinan's answer, here is a "parser" written from the other side of the camel.

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @ops;
use overload map {
    my $op = $_;
    $op => sub {
        my ($x, $y) = @_[$_[2] ? (1, 0) : (0, 1)];
        bless [$x, $op, $y]
    }
} @ops = qw(+ - / *);

my %ops = map {$_ => eval "sub {\$_[0] $_ \$_[1]}"} @ops;

sub eval {
    my $self = shift;
    return $$self[0] if @$self == 1;

    my ($x, $op, $y) = map {ref eq 'main' ? $_->eval : $_} @$self;

    my $ret = $ops{$op}->($x, $y);
    say "$ret = $x $op $y";
    $ret;
}

BEGIN {overload::constant integer => sub {bless [$_[1]]}}

eval->eval for "@ARGV";
```

Which when run:

```
$ perl eval.pl 2*3+2*5
```

prints:

```
6 = 2 * 3
10 = 2 * 5
16 = 6 + 10
```